# importing CSV direct from downloadble link using R

Tags: r

I want to directly import the dataset from the following URL directly into R to work with the data:

`http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2223/B1.csv`

Previously I have used `read_csv()` or `fread()` like this:

```
data <- data.table::fread("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2223/B1.csv")
data <- readr::read_csv("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2223/B1.csv")
```

This used to work with the data being in a data.frame, and looking like the original data.  However, now the output appears to be HTML:

e.g. if using `read_csv()`

```
head(data)
# A tibble: 6 x 1
  `<HTML>`                                                                                                                                          
  <chr>                                                                                                                                             
1 "<HEAD>"                                                                                                                                          
2 "<TITLE>Football Betting | Football Results | Free Bets | Betting Odds</TITLE>"                                                                   
3 "<meta name=\"twitter:card\" content=\"summary\" />"                                                                                              
4 "<meta name=\"twitter:site\" content=\"@12Xpert\" />"                                                                                             
5 "<meta name=\"twitter:title\" content=\"Football-Data.co.uk\" />"
```

Is there a way to directly import the csv from such a downloadable link, without having to download the excel file onto your computer and then loading it?

Comment: Is the target URL correct? If you key this into a browser, you end up (on a default webpage, i.e. ) https://www.football-data.co.uk/. The content you see is the header of this page. Thus, I assume the data file you are looking for is not existing, has another name, or has been removed. I am unsure what you mean with downloading the excel file (which I fail to see as well on the given URL). Obviously, you could download an excel file and open this with {readxl} or friends.

Comment: This url is located on this page:  https://www.football-data.co.uk/belgiumm.php   There are a list of excel files available for download.  The URL above is the one for the first excel file listed.  However, when I try and read this URL in directly (the one above), it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: c.f. below/above: target link!, if you use `https` instead of `http` your download will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goede morgen Jalapic, I think you are almost there.

Short answer - check your download link. You will have success with `https` (and not `http://....`

```
bets2223 <- readr::read_csv("https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2223/B1.csv")
```

Longer answer. You can always work out your links by using tools that the R ecosystem offers.

```
library(rvest)    # package to download web-content
library(dplyr)    # tidyverse data wrangling
library(readr)    # tidyverse read package

# check the page given by Jalapic
# and extract all `href` links
page  <- read_html("https://www.football-data.co.uk/belgiumm.php")
links <- page %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_attr("href")

# the list can be reduced to our "payload" mmz... files
links    <- links[grepl(pattern = "^mmz4281", x = links)]
base_url <-  "https://www.football-data.co.uk/"

# construct a vector of all links that fit our search patters
download_urls <- paste0(base_url, links)
download_urls[1:4]      # to shorten the output - show only first 4 results
```

This yields

```
[1] "https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2223/B1.csv" "https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2122/B1.csv"
[3] "https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/2021/B1.csv" "https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1920/B1.csv"
```

Ok. We now spot the right file name (or write a loop to download all files of interest).
For your case we pick the first one, i.e. `download_urls[1]`.

```
bets2223 <- read_csv(download_urls[1])
glimpse(bets2223)
```

This gets us what we are looking for (note: truncated for presentation purposes):

```
Rows: 134
Columns: 105
$ Div         <chr> "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B…
$ Date        <chr> "22/07/2022", "23/07/2022", "23/07/2022", "23/07/2022", "23/07/2022", "24/07/2022", "24/07/2022", "24/07/2022", "24/07/202…
$ Time        <time> 19:45:00, 15:00:00, 17:15:00, 17:15:00, 19:45:00, 12:30:00, 15:00:00, 17:30:00, 20:00:00, 19:45:00, 15:00:00, 17:15:00, 1…
$ HomeTeam    <chr> "Standard", "Charleroi", "Kortrijk", ...
```

Comment: this is great - thanks. I should have realized to check the links via `rvest`.  Good idea!